# Switching off wireless card

Tags: wireless, networking, bluetooth

I have HP 250 G2 laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 (dual-boot).
On my keyboard I have wireless on/off button (fn+F12), which turns Wi-Fi and Bluetooth on/off, but this works only on Windows. On Ubuntu this button does nothing. However, this isn't a problem, since you can switch Wi-Fi and Bluetooth  on/off via network applet.
The problem is a led light indicating wireless card status. On Windows the light changes from white to red, when I turn off both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. On Ubuntu it stays white, even when I turn off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth (via applet).

Question: Is the card really powered off, even if the light is white? (I would like the card to be switched off for better battery time.)

P.S.: One time, when I was using mobile broadband connection and I switched Wi-Fi off (in applet), the light went red, and when I turned it on again, it became white... but I was unable to re-create this again.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The problem actually solved itself: When I use laptop on battery power (AC disconnected), the led light is red, meaning the wireless card is really off. Probably because off power saving settings, and that was what I wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for battery consumption with `powertop`

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

If the card was still active, it would be among the first entries consuming the most power.

[powertop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/powertop) has some more usefull hints, where you can save battery time